# Javascript - requestAnimationFrame Frame Rate

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a sprite sheet animation where I am using requestAnimationFrame method to animate a spritesheet with only 4 images on the sheet This is my code:
http://hyque.com/ryan/ani-ryan-2.html
The problem is that it is too fast at 60 fps, so I want to slow the fps. I have been reading several articles on different ways to do it using either setInterval or Date(). I can’t seem to get the code to work correctly. Can anyone help, please.
Here is one of the articles that I tried to merge into my code:
http://codetheory.in/controlling-the-frame-rate-with-requestanimationframe/

Comment: How about a simple setInterval?

Comment: Please post the code in the question.  An external link is no use to someone looking for help with the same problem, if it's no longer available.

Comment: basically: remove the requestAnimation calls and use: setInterval(animate, your_framerate);

Comment: You do **not** want to use `setInterval`; stick with rAF. Within your rAF handler, check the time and skip that turn if necessary to achieve a lower frame rate.

Answer (score 4):

So what I like to use to control animation  apart form the "game loop."

```
var lastRender = 0;
var counter = 0;
function render(time)
{
    //checks to see if enough time has passed
    if(time - lastRender<16){requestAnimationFrame(render);return;}
    lastRender = time;
    counter++;
    if(counter %20 && counter != 0)
       animation();
    if(counter >= 60)
         counter=0;
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

This gives you greater control over your sprites so you can now have them at different speeds and your logic stays at 60fps.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, for Game Engines you will want your rendering speed to be different from your logic speed.

Logic speed should simply be as fast as possible

> setInterval( logic, 0 ); // runs as fast as possible

OR

> setTimer( logic, 0 ); // logic() runs this again ( i think this is generally better )

Whereas render should remain as you have it, as fast as rendering is done

> requestAnimationFrame( render ) // per render frame

However, requestAnimationFrame is unstable between machines, and for the most part will run 60 frames per second ( depending on the users hardware ).

In this case, for consistency you should base your animation on consistent TIME or setTimeout.

In your animation you could use something like

> var date = new Date(), // date object
>
> milliseconds = date.getMilliseconds(), // 0 - 999 of the second
>
> totalSpriteFrames = 4
>
> frame = Math.floor( milliseconds / ( 1000 / totalSpriteFrames ) ); // break the second into four frames

Create the date object outside of your animation scope for optimization, and this math can easily be used to choose which " frame " your sprite is on.  You can also use this for multiple sprites, just change their " totalSpriteFrames "

This is also scalable in case you end up with a frame heavy sprite with many frames.

Comment: Thanks for all of the suggestions, but I have tried a bunch different things. I think my problem is that I'm not getting the code implemented into what I already have which is :

Comment: I have tried a lot of these types of thing, and thanks for all the great suggestions, They never work when I try to add them to my existing code. Can anyone point me to where I can see an entire sprite animation using requestAnimationFrame() and slowing down the frame rate. I tried to past my code into here as suggested, but it says it is too long. The link is above in my original question. I just can't seem to get the addional code implemented correctly.